# Any good examples of mode-less windows for mobile?

Tags: mobile-application, mobile-web

For example, let's say I'm editing an object and I reach a field that needs certain data. But the data is elsewhere in the app. Rather than abandoning my changes, I would prefer for the app to save my changes so I can later return to the object, fill in the data, and hit Save. Has anyone seen this kind of functionality on a phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you need a save button for your object, so that you can save your completed work and later you collect the data and again come to the object and filled the rest data and click on save or submit again.

And bay be you can have auto save function.

Comment: Yes, the object needs a Save button, but I need the object, with current changes, to stay open until I return with the needed data.

Auto-save is a good thought, but I don't think it will work for this application since we can't save the object until all required fields are supplied.

Comment: You can save half collected data right. Later when you open that object you can enter unfilled data and hit save again.

Comment: When user hits Save we return an error that required fields are not supplied. User then needs to leave the work in progress, get data elsewhere in the system, return to the item, enter data and click Save. What we need is a place for the work in progress to live while the user goes and gets data. I've been thinking about saving "Drafts."

Comment: Saving data as a draft will also work.

Comment: Yes, I agree that auto-saving work as a draft is the best way to go. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yes, It is a good practice. I usually do. :) Your Welcome

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need a picker, if the information the user would fish for is structured (date, file, contact, order#, etc.)

The most common types of pickers are dates, files, time, but you can create your own custom picker for your own data type and flow. This is particularly important for complex information in a large information space, like picking a contact in a phonebook, where you might want to help users select by first name, last name, or even add a filter / search feature.

Examples of pickers:

Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Google material: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/pickers.html#pickers-time-pickers

jQuery UI: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

jquery plugin image picker: http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

Comment: You're assuming the form knows what the user will need to fish for. I would not make that assumption. Besides, users might want to finish their work later for any number of reasons. Maybe they started entering data and then were interrupted with a a phone call that took them into a different part of the app. Pickers don't solve that.